# Machine learning, kNN and Naïve Bayes algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, clustering

This is the task I am working on:

> In this assignment you will implement the K-Nearest Neighbour and Naïve Bayes algorithms and evaluate them on a real dataset using the stratified cross validation method. You will also evaluate the performance of other classifiers on the same dataset using Weka. Finally, you will investigate the effect of feature selection, in particular the Correlation-based Feature Selection method (CFS) from Weka.

I have done the weka part and also written seperate code for performance evaluation. Here, I need help with the main code where I am implementing kNN and NB algorithm.

Here is my code! I want to reduce the number of lines and possibly make it look more neat. Please help as much as you can. I have tried splitting into more functions and then calling them to do the work but is there a way I can do more? Also, is there a way the for loops can be written more compactly?

```
import heapq
import sys
import math as m
from decimal import Decimal
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Comment: Thanks for editing. It would also be helpful to reviewers if you provided a sample of what the input files look like.

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: @RafiulNakib is this a homework? Can you use ML packages like sklearn or at least numpy or does it need to be done in pure Python only?

Comment: Yes this is a homework assignment, I am not allowed to use any of the built-in classification libraries.